# Get date-time from past date-time + duration

Tags: momentjs

The service returns a past date-time in `ISO 8601` format like `2018-03-23T08:00:00Z` and a duration in `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` format like: `PT3H`. From those 2 values I need to calculate the date-time of the end of the duration. So in my case it would be `2018-03-23T11:00:00Z`.
I'm using `moment.js` for this. The problem is, when I'm tring to get the duration end date-time it returns a human readable string like `in xy hours`.

The problems I'm facing:

1. It returns wrong duration. If I have `PT3H` it should return `in 3 hours` but it returns `in 9 hours` instead.
2. The end date-time should be in milliseconds, currently its in "human readable form"

My code:

```
let dur = moment.duration("PT3H");
let myDate = moment("2018-03-23T08:00:00Z");
myDate.from(dur); // It returns "in 9 hours"
```

[JsBin](https://jsbin.com/daxiwohoyu/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your duration to your date using [`add(Duration)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) and then use [`from`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/).

Note that [`from`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/) accepts: `Moment|String|Number|Date|Array` while, in your code, you are passing a duration (`dur`).

You can use [`diff`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) to get the difference in milliseconds.

If you want to get Unix timestamp of a moment object you can use [`valueOf()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/).

Here a live sample:

```js
let dur = moment.duration("PT3H");
let myDate = moment("2018-03-23T08:00:00Z");
let m2 = myDate.clone().add(dur);
console.log(m2.from(myDate));

let diff = m2.diff(myDate);
console.log(diff);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @VincenzoC, it solves the first issue. But how can I convert it to milliseconds?

Comment: Got it. `m2.valueOf()` will do the trick. Can you add this to your answer? Then I will accept it.